# How to setVisibility to a particular layer when clicked?- Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have more than 10 layers , where i have to set one layer to visibility when clicked , I tried a code and its not working. I dont know how to make it better.

```
 var mapClick = [layer1,layer2,layer3......]
  if (mapClick == 'layer1'){
      layer.setVisibility(true)
  }
  else {
    layer.setVisibility(false)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify layer visibility with `layer.setVisible(true/false)`, not setVisibility.

Here the API reference: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html#setVisible